# IONIC SIDEBAR LAG

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created an ionic app, currently i used the default side-menu of ionic app. I added image in the side-menu and text from providers that i made but the problem now is if every time i open the app when i press the menu button the slides is delay/laggy but when i tap in second time the slides is not delay/laggy. The delay or lag for side-menu is everytime the app open. Is these a cache problem or providers?

Here's the status

1. Side-menu delay every 1st tap in every app opens
2. Side-menu not delay in 2nd tap
3. Android only

Here's my app.html

[image]

## UPDATED

When i click this:

[image]

> Ionic:
>
> > ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic) 
> >        Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2 
> >        @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
>
> Cordova:
>
> > cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 
> >     Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5 
> >     Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 24 other plugins)
>
> System:
>
> > Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/alfrancis/Library/Android/sdk) 
> >     ios-deploy        : 2.0.0 
> >     NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node) 
> >     npm               : 5.6.0 
> >     OS                : macOS High Sierra 
> >     Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless here. Code is written as text, and should be copied and pasted into your question in that form.

Comment: You need the snippets, sorry for that. This question is solved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use `menuClose` attr for menu items.

Why don't you use `menuToggle` instead? Thanks for attention.

Refer to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/MenuToggle/) as well.

Comment: i added an image for clarification that when i press the menutoggle the app slides delay/laggy, what is the different between menuClose and Toggle?

Comment: Why on first click the sidebar lags/delay?

Comment: would u prefer to this issue - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6645 ?
It's closed now.